# Creating Master (Template) Pages in HTML

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, master-pages

I have been looking into master pages for html.  I have came across a few options; using iFrames, jquery, or php.  However, I haven't really found any solid information on which is best or how to even get started with one.  My question is:  What should I use to create master pages for html pages?
I am not using anything related to Visual Studio, just regular HTML, PHP, jquery, javascript, and stuff like that.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stay away from iFrames and use PHP.

Primitively, have separate pages for your header, body content and footers:

- `header.php` (contains your document type, media includes (stylesheets, icons, etc.) and everything else before and including the `<body>` tag. You may wish to include anything else you want to be displayed on all pages in this file (e.g., a site title, an image, etc.)
- `footer.php` (contains the footer which will be on every page, including the end body and HTML tag)
- `index.php` (contains the content for your home page)

**header.php**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Site</title>
</head>
<body>
```

**index.php**

In `index.php`, you would use [PHP include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) to include the header and footer in your main page:

```
<?php include('header.php'); ?>

    <h1>Welcome to my Site</h1>

<?php include('footer.php'); ?>
```

**footer.php**

```
<p>Thanks for visiting.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Would this work with "header.html" as the include parameter, instead of having like "header.php" ?

Comment: Yes it will. But it can often make your life easier if you use .php (in case you want to add PHP to these pages later, it would be a pain going back changing the extension of all your includes).

Comment: I'm sorry for so many questions, I am just not that familiar with a lot of web development.  So the header.php file is just a basic html file with added php to help with different functionality (like master pages)?

Comment: Just updated my comment above. Essentially, you are correct. You can write normal HTML and JavaScript with the bonus of executing/running PHP (e.g., for using PHP include above).